# Single page architecture or application in web site in html navigation using servlet without opening a new page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

Actually I want to download the files using a servlet on click of link.

I am using single page architecture or application in web site in HTML.

**How to call servlet on clicking of a link without change in page?**

I am trying but next page is opening so can I restrict the opening a new page on link? I want to make a dynamic web page. I want to load the image on click of the link.

Here is some code:

```
<form action="./dwfile" method="get or post">
   <a class="btn_loadmore btn btn-lg btn-orange" href="dwfile?#templatemo-archives" role="button">DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOTS</a>
</form>
```

When the users click on `DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOT` link then they remain on the same page and the dwfile servlet should be invoked, i.e folder will be downloaded. And they will navigate to the next template i.e. #templatemo-XXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `form` tag so every time your form is submitted.

> when the user click on DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOT link then it remains
>   on a same page and the dwfile servlet should be invoked.

Then there is no need of `form` tag here. Only a link needed to download your file. Just use

```
<a href="dwfile" class="btn btn-success">DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOT</a>
```

Comment: how how could i navigate to other part( or Templet) of a page. i would say you are 99.995 correct.

Comment: for this use target attribute of href. @user3831798

Comment: it openes a new page i want a navingation on same page like some times i used  <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a class="btn btn-orange" href="#" role="button">21 February 2084</a>
                                </div>   it will jump on home page or a home templet

Comment: are using like `target="_blank"` then new tab will be opened @user3831798

Comment: i dont want any tab to invoke. i want only the navigation to the home templet

Comment: hey can used this answer with different href values with in a same page

Comment: actually i want to submit the contact details and give the console message to the user using servlet **successfully submitted the form**

Answer (score 0):

Use the target attribute to determite how the href should be executed.

**More informations:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

For e.g.:

```
   <a class="btn_loadmore btn btn-lg btn-orange" href="dwfile?#templatemo-archives" target="_blank" role="button">DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOTS</a>
```

If you want to really make it dynanimc you should think about using httpRequests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: how how could i navigate to other part( or Templet) of a page. i would say you are 99.995 correct.

Comment: when i hit to the DOWNLOAD MORE SCREENSHOT the it shoud navigate to the home part of a single page arch. of a page.

Comment: ah now I get it. Then you have to add the div id to the end of url like: http://google.com#searchbar

Comment: hey can used this answer with different href values with in a same page

Comment: I don't know why this happens with me....   some this code will not invoked new page and some times it invoke the page. And one more intresting thing is that, this code works on my desktop but it not working on laptop.  Even i check the code byte by bye and also copy paste but not working on my laptop.  Please provife me solution it my Accademic  project

Comment: above link is not not working giv me ur mobile.no we chat on whatsapp

Comment: hey, I don't have whatsapp. You can join us in the javascript room whenever you want. We will welcome you.